# Plant dependence on CO₂ levels

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, climate-change

I was wondering which kind of plants would survive longest without CO<sub>2</sub> : plants with fatty, thick leaves or plants with thinner, less fatty leaves? 
And can we conclude that the plant species that are more dependent on CO<sub>2</sub> levels, would benefit from the greenhouse effect?

Answer (score 1):

Plants do not need CO<sub>2</sub> for survival. They need it just for photosynthesis; if you supply them with alternate carbon source such as glucose then they would survive (See [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC429343/) for non-CO<sub>2</sub> Carbon-source utilization). There are non-photosynthetic plants which are totally dependent on carbon sources other than CO<sub>2</sub>; some are carnivorous like venus fly-trap.

I am not sure what you intend when you correlate leaf thickness to CO<sub>2</sub>-dependence. Leaf morphology can affect photosynthesis rates but afaik there is no relationship between leaf morphology and CO<sub>2</sub>-**dependence**.

> can we conclude that the plant species that are more dependent on
>   CO<sub>2</sub> levels, would benefit from the greenhouse effect

Greenhouse effect is not equivalent to increase in CO<sub>2</sub>; increased CO<sub>2</sub> levels can cause greenhouse effect which is a physical phenomenon of entrapment of IR radiation.

CO<sub>2</sub> is fixed by an enzyme called Rubisco; like most enzyme catalyzed reactions this will reach a saturation limit i.e. addition of more CO<sub>2</sub> will not increase the rate of photosynthesis. However the rate of photosynthesis is limited at the Rubisco step because of low levels of CO<sub>2</sub> (See [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-6709-9_191)) and it can be expected that most photosynthetic plants will be benefited by increase in CO<sub>2</sub>. However, not all plants would be resistant to increased temperatures and moreover the rate of enzyme catalysis would also change with temperature. So it is not that easy to predict.